# .app Created with PyInstaller is Unable to Create Any Files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have used PyInstaller to create a standalone/windowed .app file using the command `pyinstaller --noconfirm --windowed main.spec` using the default .spec file.

I then use `pkgbuild` and `productbuild` to create installers. However, whenever I run my program after using the installer, I am utterly unable to create files. For example, with the default logging module, when my program hits the line `fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(resource_path("log.log"))` the program crashes with `PermissionError [errorno 13] permission denied`. Note that the resource_path function is:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

I have seen some tutorials and threads saying that the error is with the location of the file. Shouldn't I be able to at least create the file from within the app's .app/Contents/MacOS directory?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was, the .pkg installs as root, and gives only the owner (root) read/write/execute permissions; everyone else only gets read/execute.

A workaround was to sudo chmod -R 777 the application as a postinstall script. To make this easier for anyone else, I setup a boilerplate application that will handle the entire process using pyinstaller and bash scripts: https://github.com/The-Nicholas-R-Barrow-Company-LLC/python3-pyinstaller-base-app-codesigning

Edit: made a library with pip: https://github.com/The-Nicholas-R-Barrow-Company-LLC/PyMacApp

Comment: Your library looks very intriguing. I'm struggling to construct a notarized .pkg from my .app, created using pyinstaller. My .spec file is fairly substantial, e.g. I have lots of data to include, numerous hidden imports, etc.


I'm able to get my app notarized and running, and I use ```productbuild``` to make the pkg. It gets notarized, but somehow still isn't created correctly since I encounter a javascript error when trying to run the installer. 


Will your library allow me to use my own .spec file?

Comment: I installed your package and looked at your basic example. I now see, looking at how you defined the ```App``` class, that the answer to my question above is yes.

Is there a way I can trouble shoot with you a simple example of my own that I'm looking at? Perhaps post as an issue on your github?

Comment: @fishbacp yea absolutely, I'm always looking to expand new features to pymacapp. Can you send me your .spec file or something similar... I can't remember how thoroughly I tested the option to use your own spec, but it should work... you can also send me the output from the pymacapp logs and I can probably troubleshoot from that

Comment: shoot me an email me@nicholasrbarrow.com and we can work on it